# R - using "next" statement in apply function

Tags: r, lapply

It looks like the `next` statement (used to stop the current evaluation and go to the next iteration of a for-loop) doesn't work inside an `apply` function.

Example: `lapply(1:10, function(x) if (x == 5) {next} else {print(x)})`

Any convenient substitution for `next` in `apply`?

Comment: When you use `lapply` you operate only on one element in your function so loop has no meaning at all.

Comment: your operation is inherently recursive, which is not what `lapply` is for. You want a `for` loop. And your simplified example is equivalent to `(1:10 -> x)[x==5]`; perhaps you'd like to try an example more similar to your actual work and we may be able to offer more helpful advice.

Comment: You can just omit the `{next} else` part; e.g. `if (x == 5) print(x)`. Or move the predicate from `lapply` to `Filter` and pass the result of that to `lapply`; `lapply(Filter(function(x) x == 5, 1:10), function(x) { ## do whatever })`.

Answer (score 10):

The short answer for cases like yours is `return`.

```
lapply(1:10, function(x) if (x == 5) {return()} else {print(x)})
```

Makes sense since the code you're applying is a function.  Obviously I'm assuming your real case is more complex, and it wouldn't work to simply omit the true arm of the `if`.

Comment: That's the correct answer and it can be more useful when removing the list objects in e.g. `do.call(rbind, lapply(list(...), function(x) ... ))`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using Hadley's **purrr** package:

```
library(purrr)
1:5 %>% map_if(~.x != 5, ~print(.x))
```

Comment: Unfortunately not applicable for my particular use (the body of my function actually contains heavy data processing, with several queries...); but very interesting example. This package looks very promising! As usual with Hadley's work...